# google maps markers add easeout effect at setMap(null)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a Googlemap with multiple markers on that I refresh when moving around or zoom in/out the map. So far so good. The problem is that if a marker is refreshed, I mean repainted on the map, then it blinks for an instance, as it first gets deleted as an old marker and then painted as a new marker. I use `setMap(null)` to hide markers. Is there a way to avoid this blinking? Is there a way f.e. to add easingout effect at `setMap(null)` using jQuery or something?

Answer (score 0):

Write your code to not do that. Don't delete all the existing markers, only delete those that no longer appear in the updated data and add new ones.

Comment: Yes but somehow i should not add the already added again. In any case it seems that setting optimized property of marker to true (by default is true), results in handling all markers as a single static element, as mentioned in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker . So by setting it to false, every marker is a single dom element and can be handled further.

Comment: If you want further advice (like suggested code modifications), please post your existing code and possibly a link to a live map or a jsfiddle that exhibits the problematic behavior.